# How to find cumulative frequency without group by in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, cumulative-frequency

I have a count column in pyspark dataframe as :

```
id   Count  Percent  
a     3       50    
b     3       50
```

I want a result dataframe as :

```
id   Count Percent CCount CPercent  
 a     3      50       3      50  
 b     3      50       6      100
```

I cant use pandas dataframe as database is very large.
I found answers pointing to window partition but i have no such column to partition by.
Please can anyone tell how to do it in pyspark dataframe.
Note : pyspark version 1.6

Comment: This might be what you were looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787753/sas-proc-freq-with-pyspark-frequency-percent-cumulative-frequency-and-cumula

Answer (score 0):

The windowing approach would require moving all data into one partition and, as you have indicated in your post, your dataset is too big for this. To get around this I have slightly adapted this [approach](http://tech.magnetic.com/2016/05/computing-distributed-groupwise-cumulative-sums-in-pyspark.html). This method calculates the cumulative sum for each partition after constructing an offset dictionary for each partition. This allows calculating the cumulative sum for each partition in parallel with minimum reshuffling of the data:

First let's generate some test data:

```
data = sc.parallelize([('a',1,25.0),('b',2,25.0),('c',3,50.0)]).toDF(['id','Count','Percent'])
```

These are the helper method I have tweaked (see the [original code](http://tech.magnetic.com/2016/05/computing-distributed-groupwise-cumulative-sums-in-pyspark.html) here)

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

def cumulative_sum_for_each_group_per_partition(partition_index, event_stream):
    cumulative_sum = defaultdict(float)
    for event in event_stream:
        cumulative_sum["Count"] += event["Count"]
        cumulative_sum["Percent"] += event["Percent"]
    for grp, cumulative_sum in cumulative_sum .iteritems():
        yield (grp, (partition_index, cumulative_sum))

def compute_offsets_per_group_factory(num_partitions):
    def _mapper(partial_sum_stream):
        per_partition_cumulative_sum = dict(partial_sum_stream)
        cumulative_sum = 0
        offset = {}
        for partition_index in range(num_partitions):
            offset[partition_index] = cumulative_sum
            cumulative_sum += per_partition_cumulative_sum.get(partition_index, 0)
        return offset
    return _mapper

def compute_cumulative_sum_per_group_factory(global_offset):
    def _mapper(partition_index, event_stream):
        local_cumulative_sum = defaultdict(float)
        for event in event_stream:
            local_cumulative_sum["Count"] += event["Count"]
            count_cumulative_sum = local_cumulative_sum["Count"] + global_offset.value["Count"][partition_index]
            local_cumulative_sum["Percent"] += event["Percent"]
            percentage_cumulative_sum = local_cumulative_sum["Percent"] + global_offset.value["Percent"][partition_index]
            yield Row(CCount= count_cumulative_sum, CPercent = percentage_cumulative_sum, **event.asDict())
    return _mapper

def compute_cumulative_sum(points_rdd):
    # First pass to compute the cumulative offset dictionary
    compute_offsets_per_group = compute_offsets_per_group_factory(points_rdd.getNumPartitions())
    offsets_per_group = points_rdd.\
        mapPartitionsWithIndex(cumulative_sum_for_each_group_per_partition, preservesPartitioning=True).\
        groupByKey().mapValues(compute_offsets_per_group).\
        collectAsMap()
    # Second pass to compute the cumulative sum using the offset dictionary
    sc = points_rdd.context
    compute_cumulative_sum_per_group = compute_cumulative_sum_per_group_factory(sc.broadcast(offsets_per_group))
    return points_rdd.\
        mapPartitionsWithIndex(compute_cumulative_sum_per_group, preservesPartitioning=True)
```

Using these helper methods on the test data:

```
compute_cumulative_sum(data.rdd).toDF().show()
```

gives:

```
+------+--------+-----+-------+---+
|CCount|CPercent|Count|Percent| id|
+------+--------+-----+-------+---+
|   1.0|    25.0|    1|   25.0|  a|
|   3.0|    50.0|    2|   25.0|  b|
|   6.0|   100.0|    3|   50.0|  c|
+------+--------+-----+-------+---+
```

Comment: Not sure if this code could be adapted to achieve the same that has been given at https://medium.com/eduonline24/can-we-get-sas-proc-freq-with-python-c6af752f387a with Pandas. This is what I'm looking for, but in PySpark. (I need the same behaviour of SAS Proc Freq as per content of the link). Perhaps worth a separated question.

Comment: Appreciate if you can address it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787753/sas-proc-freq-with-pyspark-frequency-percent-cumulative-frequency-and-cumula

Comment: Hi @Alex - I have tried to apply it to this other problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787753/sas-proc-freq-with-pyspark-frequency-percent-cumulative-frequency-and-cumula/65788004?noredirect=1#comment116334459_65788004, but no success. Could you help taking a look at it? Appreciate your help!