# SAS Proc Freq with PySpark (Frequency, percent, cumulative frequency, and cumulative percent)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, statistics, cumulative-frequency

I'm looking for a way to reproduce the SAS Proc Freq code in PySpark. I found [this code that does exactly what I need](https://medium.com/eduonline24/can-we-get-sas-proc-freq-with-python-c6af752f387a). However, it is given in Pandas.
I want to make sure it does use the best what Spark can offer, as the code will run with massive datasets. [In this other post](http://tech.magnetic.com/2016/05/computing-distributed-groupwise-cumulative-sums-in-pyspark.html) ([which was also adapted for this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907258/7224879)), I also found instructions to compute distributed groupwise cumulative sums in PySpark, but not sure how to adapt it to my end.

Here's an input and output example (my original dataset will have a couple of billions rows):

**Input dataset:**

```
        state
0       Delaware
1       Delaware
2       Delaware
3       Indiana
4       Indiana
...     ...
1020    West Virginia
1021    West Virginia
1022    West Virginia
1023    West Virginia
1024    West Virginia

1025 rows × 1 columns
```

**Expected output:**

```
    state           Frequency   Percent Cumulative Frequency    Cumulative Percent
0   Vermont         246         24.00   246                     24.00
1   New Hampshire   237         23.12   483                     47.12
2   Missouri        115         11.22   598                     58.34
3   North Carolina  100         9.76    698                     68.10
4   Indiana         92          8.98    790                     77.07
5   Montana         56          5.46    846                     82.54
6   West Virginia   55          5.37    901                     87.90
7   North Dakota    53          5.17    954                     93.07
8   Washington      39          3.80    993                     96.88
9   Utah            29          2.83    1022                    99.71
10  Delaware        3           0.29    1025                    100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first group by state to get the frequency and percent, then use `sum` over a window to get the cumulative frequency and percent:

```
result = df.groupBy('state').agg(
    F.count('state').alias('Frequency')
).selectExpr(
    '*',
    '100 * Frequency / sum(Frequency) over() Percent'
).selectExpr(
    '*',
    'sum(Frequency) over(order by Frequency desc) Cumulative_Frequency', 
    'sum(Percent) over(order by Frequency desc) Cumulative_Percent'
)

result.show()
+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
|        state|Frequency|Percent|Cumulative_Frequency|Cumulative_Percent|
+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
|West Virginia|        5|   50.0|                   5|              50.0|
|     Delaware|        3|   30.0|                   8|              80.0|
|      Indiana|        2|   20.0|                  10|             100.0|
+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks!
I have also achieve the same by changing the Pandas solution I shared over the question text by replacing the `datax = data['state'].value_counts()` for `datax = df.groupBy('state').count().sort(col("count").desc()).toPandas().set_index('state')['count']` and stick with Pandas from this point on. I also got the same results, but I think your solution is better. Do you know if your solution will scale and work with multiple partitions? Considering my data will have billions of rows? Still on my text question, there's a link to another (similar) solution that takes it into account.

Comment: You can try it out :) I can't make any predictions, many factors could affect whether code works or not.

Comment: Yep, I'm getting some warnings: `WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.` Work to figure out the best way to set the partitions...

Comment: The warning comes from the part after the grouped aggregation. I wouldn't worry about that, given that there are only about 50 states in USA.

Comment: This is just an example dataset for the purpose of this question @mck. My real ones has billions of records :) I need to address.

Comment: @BrunoAmbrozio but how many rows are there after the grouping? The warning is only relevant for the operations after grouping - try doing only `df.groupBy(...).count()` and you shouldn't see any warnings.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where should I do the `df.groupBy(...).count()`? Could you please edit the code in order to avoid the warnings? I'm trying to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42891203/how-to-find-cumulative-frequency-without-group-by-in-pyspark-dataframe/42907258#42907258 but not success yet.

Comment: @BrunoAmbrozio the warnings are irrelevant to the billions of rows from your dataset. It only results from the code **after** grouping, which means there are only 50 rows (1 for each USA state). Please don't worry about the warnings.